# how to set onclick Imageview is on other Imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am have a xml layout, when I set onClick in java code to imageview with the id `iv_contact` and imageview with id `iv_user`, the imageview on top doesn't work, it caught the onClick event of the bottom ImageView, how to solve this problem?

This is my xml layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl_contains_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_video_send"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp12"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp12"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp16"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="@dimen/dp110"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@dimen/dp175">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the setOnClick code:

```
ivImageUser.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(getIntent, REQUEST_USER_IMAGE);
});
ivContact.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(getIntent, REQUEST_CONTACT_IMAGE);
});
```

I tried different ways like setting `android:clickable="true"` however the results are not very positive, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you just change the intent object with different name like getIntent and getIntent1 and try once

Comment: I think it's about the Z-order of the views layed out. It could also be that your cardview isn't forwarding the click event to its children. Have you tried to set `android:clickable="true"` on your cardview?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please Use iv_contact Imageview Bottom of CardView it will work.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_video_send"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_12dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/text_size_16"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="175dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_min="@dimen/margin_110dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the request codes `REQUEST_USER_IMAGE` & `REQUEST_CONTACT_IMAGE` have  different values e.g. `REQUEST_USER_IMAGE = 100`  & `REQUEST_CONTACT_IMAGE = 200` And handle it accordingly in `onActivityResult()`

```
if(requestCode == 100)
    doSomeOperations();
else if(requestCode == 200)
    doSomeMoreOperations();
```

NOTE:
Don't use deprecated method `startActivityForResult()`. Not Recommended.
Try this way:

```
public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}

// You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    doSomeOperations();
                }
            }
        });
```